# How can you predict/get the next ChangeSetId before checking in files using TFS SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a requirement to build a Custom TFS Policy using C# & the TFS 2010 SDK.  This policy would validate that a custom note (bug #) are populated in the TFS Checkin dialog and then update a Bug Tracking system upon successful validation of the bug #.

Once I have the bug # validated, I would then use the Bug Tracking systems SDK to update the bug # with the names of the source files & the ChangeSetID.

The problem i'm having is that it appears the TFS SDK does not provide the functionality to get me the next available ChangeSetID that will be used as part of the checkin.  There doesn't seem to be a way to get this information.  Direct DB Access is not an option (I was thinking about doing something along the lines of SELECT ChangeSetId.nextVal).

Can someone let me know if this is an option with the TFS SDK?  I am trying to update the bug tracking system at the time my Custom Policy runs so I don't have to create another process to update the bug tracking system after the fact.

---

I added a client event handler for the TFS Server (CommitCheckin event), and i was able to do what i wanted from there.  Is there any problems that I will run into if I do it client side by subscribing to this event?  [CommitCheckin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.commitcheckineventhandler.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it should be two separate things:

1. A policy to ensure that the bug number is filled in
2. A custom event handler to handle the check-in event. This will naturally have access to the changeset number, and can update the bug tracking system.

Comment: In regards to item #2, would this handler be on the client side or server side?  Any good web references would also be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: @house: it would be server side. See [Team Foundation Server Event Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx) and [Extending Team Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx) in general.

Comment: @house: what I mean is that the subscription is server-side. It doesn't matter where the subscriber is.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this would be possible. Even if you could get the next id then there is no guarantee that someone else would not use it before you.

What if the check-in was done into a branch - you then use the checkin id of the branch and then once validated you merged the branch with the main line?

Comment: im sure you're theory would work, but there are political reasons within the organization on not doing any branches outside of the SW Development Process (which would not include tools like the one i'm writing)

Comment: In that case I suspect you will have to link things with a formatted comment - a guid that you put into the comment that ties back to the tracking system. If you go down the route you are trying and succeed - I doubt you would create a durable system.